# Doesn't save the result of previous 2 values if i put 3rd value for addtion

Tags: java, android

Sir I want to know, how to put here my condition that it must add previous result with current value by pressing Add Button, instead of this it just add current and previous value, please help me

```
btn_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override   
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Value1 = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText() + "");
                Add = true ;
                ed1.setText(null);
            }

        });
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Can you show us some data which describes the problem?  What is your `onClick()` method supposed to be doing exactly?

Comment: Where are previous and current values stored?

Comment: Let suppose that I have data like 23.56.89.88.90.1234.3445.

Comment: Let suppose that I have data like 23.56.89.88.90.1234.3445. now I want to add them all and want to get result. but this code is giving me result like that 23+56+36=92 not 115. mean it make addition of just to previous values         ...................

Comment: Create a static variable which will hold your total value

Comment: No addition is done at all in your code snippet.

Comment: #Jeva, mean Value1 should static?

Comment: #Henry, Let suppose that I have data like 23.56.89.88.90.1234.3445. now I want to add them all and want to get result. but this code is giving me result like that 23+56+36=92 not 115. mean it make addition of just to previous values

Comment: "this code is giving me result like that 23+56+36=92": the code you have shown is not even doing that. Be sure to show **all relevant code** (but please not more than that)

Comment: #Henry  I have paste my code...could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

**#Tim Biegeleisen, #Henry, #NiVeR 54, # Jeeva here has given up my code**

**what you would suggest?**

package com.example.maher.androidspinnertutorial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class calculatr extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btn_1,btn_2,btn_3,btn_4,btn_5,btn_6,btn_7,btn_8,btn_9,btn_0,btn_Add,btn_Sub,btn_Mul,btn_Div,btn_calc,btn_dec,btn_clear;

EditText ed1;



 float Value1, Value2;

boolean mAddition, mSubtract, mMultiplication, mDivision ;



@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculatr);



    btn_0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_0);

    btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);

    btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);

    btn_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3);

    btn_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_4);

    btn_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_5);

    btn_6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_6);

    btn_7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_7);

    btn_8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_8);

    btn_9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_9);

    btn_Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);

    btn_Div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Div);

    btn_Sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Sub);

    btn_Mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Mul);

    btn_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calc);

    btn_dec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dec);

    btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edText1);



    btn_0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"0");

        }

    });



    btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"1");

        }

    });



    btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"2");

        }

    });



    btn_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"3");

        }

    });



    btn_4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"4");

        }

    });



    btn_5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"5");

        }

    });



    btn_6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"6");

        }

    });



    btn_7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"7");

        }

    });



    btn_8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"8");

        }

    });



    btn_9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+"9");

        }

    });



    btn_dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText(ed1.getText()+".");

        }

    });



    btn_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Value1 = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText() + "");

            mAddition = true ;

            ed1.setText(null);


        }

    });



    btn_Sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Value1 = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText() + "");

            mSubtract = true ;

            ed1.setText(null);

        }

    });



    btn_Mul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Value1 = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText() + "");

            mMultiplication = true ;

            ed1.setText(null);

        }

    });



    btn_Div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Value1 = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText()+"");

            mDivision = true ;

            ed1.setText(null);

        }

    });



    btn_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Value2 = Float.parseFloat(ed1.getText() + "");



            if (mAddition == true){



                ed1.setText(Value1 + Value2 +"");

                mAddition=false;

            }





            if (mSubtract == true){

                ed1.setText(Value1 - Value2 +"");

                mSubtract=false;

            }



            if (mMultiplication == true){

                ed1.setText(Value1 * Value2 + "");

                mMultiplication=false;

            }



            if (mDivision == true){

                ed1.setText(Value1 / Value2+"");

                mDivision=false;

            }

        }

    });



    btn_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            ed1.setText("");

        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: #Tim Biegeleisen, #Henry, #NiVeR 54, # Jeeva here has given up my code